# $L^{2}(\Omega)$ estimate of a exponential.

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to prove that: if $\left\| u \right\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)} \leq 1$, exists $\sigma$, K such that 
$$\left\| e^{\sigma |u(.)|^{2}} \right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq K.$$

I've tried so far:
If $u$ has this limitation, then $\left\| u \right\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq 1$, but with that, maybe I'll need:
If $\int_{\Omega}|u|^{2}\leq 1,$ than exists $\epsilon$ such $|u|^{2} \leq \epsilon$, and I don't know if this is true.

Comment: What is the dimension of $\Omega$? Is it a bounded set? This might be important here.

Comment: Yes, a bounded with regular boundary

Comment: ops, i forgot the dimension. $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$, a bounded set with regular boundary.